# Boost converter with pulse skipping modulation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

With boost converter using pulse skipping modulation, how is it possible for it to keep output voltage constant when load current increases?
When load current increases, the output voltage decreases significantly and the pulse is switched on. But even the pulse is on with duty cycle fixed, the output voltage will decrease.

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously, when the load current increases, the controller must skip fewer pulses. At some point, it is skipping none of them, and it must increase the width of the pulses in order to continue to provide more output power.

Pulse skipping provides poorer regulation than PWM, which is why it is normally only used as an alternative method to increase efficiency at lower load currents.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was confused. When there is no pulse skipped but the load current still remains constant so the output voltage will decrease. To solve this, the pulse width need to be increased.